# Did John kiss Cameron?

Tags: character, terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles*, John and Cameron seem to have some kind of deep connection.

Is there any scene of John and Cameron kissing or hugging each other, even in the deleted scenes?